# What is the best way to deploy a Craft CMS 3 site?

Tags: craft3, best-practice, deployment

I'm unclear as to the best way to deploy a Craft CMS 3 site. I'm looking for some best practices and guidance.

I'm currently using Rocketeer to deploy the code from my local environment to my staging site. When I do this I get a ServiceUnavailableHttpException. Do I need to install Craft again once it's been deployed to my staging environment? I don't think I need to but I can't figure out why I'm getting this error.

In the past, I've run Craft 2 sites successfully by installing once on each environment and then gitignoring the common files that I want to share. I have a hook in my Rocketeer file that creates symlinks to the common files/directories.

I've thought about taking a similar approach with my Craft 3 site but am unclear as how I would do that now that the the core craft files are required within composer. Move all the core packages to require-dev in my composer file?

Who can help steer me in the right direction?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4):

At the risk of offering a "link answer", the [Setting up a New Craft CMS 3 Project](https://nystudio107.com/blog/setting-up-a-craft-cms-3-project) has a section on **DEPLOYING CRAFT CMS** that should be useful to you.

I've never heard of Rocketeer, but popular ways to handle deployments are via [buddy.works](http://buddy.works/), [Laravel Forge](https://forge.laravel.com/) and the like. We talk a lot about this on the [Website Deployment without Tears](https://devmode.fm/episodes/website-deployment-without-tears) episode of [devMode.fm](https://devmode.fm/)

Answer (score 1):

I guess you're seeing this notice, because of pending migrations after an update. After you deployed the repository, you should make sure that:

1. Run `composer install --no-interaction` to install current versions of Craft and Plugins (I guess that already works in your deploy)
2. Run `./craft migrate/all --interactive=0`. This will run pending migrations
3. Run `./craft project-config/apply --interactive=0`. This will apply the current project-config
4. Run `clear-caches/compiled-templates --interactive=0` to clear the cache
5. Run `clear-caches/cp-resources --interactive=0` to clear the cache
6. Run `clear-caches/data --interactive=0` to clear the cache

That said, Andrew's links are all worth reading and give all these answers.